# Contracts invoked asynchronously are not packaged as transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I use the sendAsync() method to call the contract asynchronously. If I loop through the method several times, without using get(), the number of packaged transactions is less than the number of calls, and data loss occurs.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet that can be used to verify the problem? I'd suggest to report to directly to web3j developers.